# How to allow auto fill of credentials in WebView App

Tags: password, webview, authentication

We have a web application and want to provide an app for it. We use a simple WebViewClient application which opens our web application. This works good.

For authentication the web application doesn't use our own site, but an external ID provider, which redirects back to our website after authentication.

The session timeout is pretty short due to reglatory reasons, so the user cannot stay logged in for a longer period of time. So we want the user to at least be able to autofill the user/password fields with credentials that are stored on the phone.

It seems like I get different behaviours on different devices. For example I have an Android 9 device and there seems to be no possibility to use stored credentials on the login form. A friend has an Android 12 and for him when he enters the password field he has this little key symbol to use stored credentials to autofill the fields by then selecting one of the stored user/password combinations.

Also in Android Studio in an emulator I don't get this option in my keyboard to use stored credentials.

So my question is. What are the requirements that this is shown on your phone? Is there a way we can set up the app to always allow the possibility to use stored credentials?

Please keep in mind that we don't have control over the login page itself, as it is hosted by the Identity provider. So we would need a solution based only in the app itself.

Comment: WebViews have most features disabled by default. So as an app programmer you can change that see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404274/make-android-webview-not-store-cookies-or-passwords. The possibility to store passwords is if I remember correctly a new feature of Android 11 or 12.

Comment: Cross-posted to Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71127799/2821954

Comment: Please note that app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users or power-users (but not necessarily developers) solving their issues. We might be able to determine the requirement, but we possibly can't help with the code.